# Determine position of sound source from arrival times of a blip ($3d$ version)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, spheres

As an extension to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866869/determine-position-of-sound-source-from-arrival-times-of-a-blip), I am now considering the problem in $3d$.

The setup is a follows:  You have four sound receivers (microphones) at known locations $P_1(x_1,y_1, z_1), P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2), P_3(x_3,y_3,z_3), P_4(x_4, y_4, z_4)$.  A sound source located somewhere in space at $P(x,y,z)$ produces a blip (a short high-pitched sound made by an electronic device) at an unknown time $t_0$.  The blip is received at the four receivers at times $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ respectively.  Use this information to determine the location of the sound source.  It is assumed that the speed of sound is known.

**My attempt:**

If $c$ is the speed of sound, and if $d_i$ is the distance travelled by sound from the source to the $i$-th receiving station, then

$$ d_i = c \ (t_i - t_0) = a_i - k $$

where $a_i = c \ t_i $ and is known for $i=1,2,3,4$ and $ k = c \ t_0 $ and is unknown.

On the other hand, we have for each of the four stations:

$d_i^2 = (P - P_i) \cdot(P - P_i) $

There are four unknowns here which are $k , x , y , z $

Now it is a matter of solving these four quadratic equations for the four unknowns.

These equations are relatively easy to solve because by subtracting pairs of equations we get

$ -2 P \cdot (P_1 - P_2) + P_1 \cdot P_1 - P_2 \cdot P_2  = a_1^2 - a_2^2 - 2 k (a_1 - a_2 ) \tag{1} $

$  -2 P \cdot (P_1 - P_3) + P_1 \cdot P_1 - P_3 \cdot P_3  = a_1^2 - a_3^2 - 2 k (a_1 - a_3 ) \tag{2}$

$  -2 P \cdot (P_1 - P_4) + P_1 \cdot P_1 - P_4 \cdot P_4  = a_1^2 - a_4^2 - 2 k (a_1 - a_4 ) \tag{3}$

Equations $(1),(2),(3)$ are linear equations of hyperplanes.  Solving the system produces a $4$-dimensional line of the form

$ X = (x,y,z, k) = X_0 + \lambda X_1 $

where both $X_0, X_1$ are known vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^4$, while $\lambda$ is a free parameter $\in \mathbb{R} $

To determine $\lambda$, substitue $X$ into any of the original four quadratic equations.  This will give a scalar quadratic  equations in $\lambda$ which produces two possible solutions.

The correct solution in which $t_0$ is less than the minimum of $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$.